# Implement cordova camera plugin using Worklight

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ibm-mobilefirst

navigator.camera.getPicture is working fine in index.html where as it is not working in subsequent html file.

navigator.camera is undefined in subsequent pages.

I have already did the check for deviceready.Already made an entry in config.xml.

I have created hybrid application in IBM worklight

Comment: How did you navigate to the "subsequent page" ? using href links?

Answer (score 3):

What you see is expected if you use href or window.location to navigate between pages in a MobileFirst/Worklight application.

A MobileFirst hybrid application uses a single DOM model.
A single DOM model means that you must never navigate between various HTML files by using hyperlinks or changing the window.location property.
Instead, you must implement multipage interfaces by loading external HTML file content, and by using Ajax requests and injecting them into the existing DOM.

This is required because the main application HTML file loads the MobileFirst client-side JavaScript™ framework files, and when the browser navigates from one HTML file to another, the JavaScript context and loaded scripts are lost.

To build a multi-page MobileFirst/Worklight application refer to this [tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/client-side-development-basics/building-a-multipage-application/).